# How to pass parameters to a bat script

Tags: batch-file

Excuse my newbie question but I haven't had to touch bat scripts since the days of the autoexec.bat... and that one was even called from the system directly.

So I wonder how I can pass in arguments to my bat script?

For example I want to create n directories with a certain name. I would like to use a construct such as this one:

```
for %%N in (1 to $arg1$) do mkdir $arg2$-%%N
```

As a result I would like to have N directories called

- name-1
- name-2
- name-3

... and so on.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the newbie question but I think at least it is in sync with Joels wish to have canonical Q&A on serverfault.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is just %1 %2 ... %n for argument1, argument2, ..., argumentn

see [this](http://www.jameskoopmann.com/2007/10/bat-script-argument-processing/) for example.

The for loop I did like this:

```
FOR %%a IN ("filename1" "filename2" "filename3") DO something %%a -clean Lib -log errors >> logfilename
```

Comment: Looks like it's your lucky day as I am on the system :-) Do you know about the loop too?

Comment: Lets look. I have a script here...

Comment: FOR %%a IN ("filename1" "filename2" "filename3") DO something %%a -clean Lib -log errors >> logfilename

Comment: Hm. Your lucky day also I'd say. :)

Answer (score 4):

Batch files use positional parameter numbers (%1, %2, %3) to indicate arguments. For your example, it would be:

for %%N in (1 to %1) do mkdir %2-%%n

Here is a [reference guide](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php).

But the construct of your for loop is incorrect too - there is no "to" keyword in batch files as far as I know. The thing in parentheses is supposed to be a set (such as: 1 2 3 4) - I'm not sure you can loop like you want to do without using labels and goto...

Here is the syntax for the [FOR command](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/for.php).

Here is how you would do the loop using labels and goto - its not pretty from a programmer's point of view - but what about a batch file is?

```
set counter=%1
set count=1
:LOOP
if %count% GEQ %counter% GOTO END
mkdir %2-%count%
set /a count = %count% + 1
goto LOOP
:END
```

Comment: Yes, the "to" for ranges does not exists... Since i am dealing with numbers, a standard for(i = 0; i < %1; i++) would do... how to?

Comment: I edited my answer to add an example of how you would do this - like I said, it isn't possible with a FOR loop as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is :

```
@echo off
for /l %%a in (1,1,%1) do mkdir Folder-%%a
```